# Spring Transactional doesn't persist an entity using EntityManager but does using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

Maybe it is kind of too common but still.

I have a small test project where I'm testing all the JPA stuff. Almost everywhere I'm using Spring Data and JPA repositories work just fine. But now I'm trying to make my service to save entities. The service looks something like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public SomeServiceImpl(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public SomeEntity save(SomeEntity someEntity) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.persist(someEntity);

        return someEntity;
}
```

The persistence config looks like this (I'm intentionally copying and pasting the whole config. Maybe it would help you to reproduce the error):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource({"classpath:conf/application.properties"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        PoolDataSourceImpl dataSource = new PoolDataSourceImpl();
        dataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setURL(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(
                Boolean.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.fast.connect.failover.enabled")));
        dataSource.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setSQLForValidateConnection("SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL");
        dataSource.setONSConfiguration(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.ons.config"));
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.initial.pool.size")));
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.min.pool.size")));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.max.pool.size")));
        dataSource.setAbandonedConnectionTimeout(0);
        dataSource.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(60 * 25);
        dataSource.setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout(0);
        dataSource.setMaxConnectionReuseTime(60 * 30L);

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.dropbinc.learning.jpa.model");

        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        Map jpaProperties = new HashMap();
        jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "drop-and-create");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Autowired EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

And one more where I'm planning to configurate the rest of the application (placed in the same package):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dropbinc.learning.jpa")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

I've tried to debug Spring but all that I wasn't able to detect a difference between transaction behaviour of JPA repositories and my service. I saw transaction was created and even commited. But in case of JPA repositories it got saved while in my service implementation it did generated ids but an entity didn't appeared in a database.

I'm running all the stuff in tests, autowiring the service by interface:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class })
public class AllTheTests {
    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;

    ...
}
```

Thank you very much for any suggestion!

**EDIT** Adding `entityManager.flush()` call generates `nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`.

Comment: does the problem occur only in tests or also in prod?

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski it is test project only. just for educational purposes

Comment: Inject the `EntityManager` NOT the `EntityManagerFactory`. You are creating a new, fresh, unmanaged instance of an `EntityManager` yourself.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks for an idea, But if I inject the `EntityManager` I will have one for the service for the whole application and I want to create one more every time. Am I understanding anything wrong?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Spring will actually inject a proxy and you will have a fresh transaction bound `EntityManager` each time you need one.

Comment: @M.Deinum so in each call to a transactional method I will get a new transaction and a new 'PersistentContext' bound to the same 'entityManager', right? Am I right now?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok, then could you proceed and make an answer?:) And I wonder if you could leave some resources recommended to understand the things right?